# How can you change the path where Hugs98 (Haskell) looks for Module and Libraries?

Tags: compiler-construction, ubuntu, haskell, hugs

I have installed Ubuntu as a virtual machine so I could use Hugs98. However, after installing I realised I couldn't use Data.Char and Data.Ratio modules. I had to load them manually with :load /usr/lib/etc . It seems this happens because the modules are not in the place where they should be. Can anyone please tell me how I can change the default path of the modules so I don't have to load them every time?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Hugs user guide](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/users_guide/options.html#OPTIONS-LIST), -P can be used to modify the search path.

However, I would strongly recommend [installing GHC](http://haskell.org/ghc), for a much more modern Haskell experience.

Comment: -P doesn't set it to default. It just sets it for one session. It worked once. Now it says it can't find Prelude.hs in that location. How can I change it for good? I can't use GHC because Hugs98 is what I need at university.

Comment: alias hugs="hugs -P..." perhaps?

Comment: I've done that. It works for some location, but it doesn't set it to default. When I try another location, where the Prelude and most modules are, it says it can't find Hugs.Prelude or Prelude along new path: "{Hugs}/packages/hugsbase/Hugs/*" ignoring it. I installed the Hugs98 version from the Ubuntu software center. What to do, please?